# Jquery Elements in a webpage not loading on webpage on clicking browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a html form page(page 1) from where I go to page 2 html page. In page 1 I have fields such as Resolution, on selecting particular resolution populates  fields such as frame-width and height(with value) which is loaded using Jquery and is disabled (just to show) Similarly I have cascaded drop-downs. On submission of this form I get the results on the same page. Also I have given option to display the output on new page. But when I get back to the previous page from new page. Jquery Elements are not loaded. Only static elements in form are loaded. Resolution stays but frame width and frame-height is not loaded. Also output on same page is also gone. How can I get to previous page as per my submission made. I am using Django in Back-end.

Index.html

```
<p><label>Resolution:</label>
        <select id="resol" name="resol" class="ip" autocomplete="off">
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="2K">2K</option>
            <option value="4KDCI">4KDCI</option>
            <option value="4KUHD">4KUHD</option>
            <option value="480p">480p</option>
            <option value="576p">576p</option>
            <option value="720p">720p</option>
            <option value="1080p">1080p</option>
            <option value="CIF">CIF</option>
            <option value="FWVGA">FWVGA</option>
            <option value="HVGA">HVGA</option>
            <option value="QCIF">QCIF</option>
            <option value="QVGA">QVGA</option>
            <option value="VGA">VGA</option>
            <option value="WVGA">WVGA</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
            <option value="all">All</option>
        </select>
        </p>
<p><label>Frame-width:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fw" name="fw" class="ip" style='visibility:hidden;' autocomplete="off">
    </p>
    <p><label>Frame-height:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fh" name="fh" class="ip" style='visibility:hidden;' autocomplete="off">
    </p>
```

Jquery to display

```
 $('#resol').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            //history.pushState(null,null,"#resolution");
            if(value=='2K'){
                $('#fw').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(2048);
                $('#fh').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(1080);
            }
            else if(value=='4KDCI'){
                $('#fw').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(4096);
                $('#fh').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(2160);
            }
            else if(value=='4KUHD'){
                $('#fw').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(3840);
                $('#fh').css('visibility','visible').attr("disabled", "disabled").val(2160);
            }
```

and so on..

new_page.html
//Displays the videos with these resolution in new page..

returning from new-page to Index.html loads the resolution selected but textBox displaying frame-width and frame-height is gone. How to store/display those values.. I am using Django in Backend.

Comment: You can either save this values in localStorage and reuse, you can also make use of cookies.

Comment: Can you elaborate this idea?

Comment: on you select change event, save option value to localstorage. Check the link for implementation. https://gomakethings.com/using-localstorage-to-save-user-data-with-vanilla-javascript/
Then when the page is loaded, call a function to check if data is there in the localstorage, if there is data, use the value get value from select option. Also add a logic to clear the localstorage

Comment: Thanks alot bro I tried storing the value in cookies as said by you referring this link:https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/ but I am unable to change the value of dropdown although the value is getting saved and I am able to alert and see the same but this is not working: if(getCookie("resolution")!=null)$('#id').trigger('change').val(getCookie("resolution"));

Comment: can you add the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Thanks alot bro it's working 2 reasons I found sofar 1)  Detecting Back-Page using this block: if(window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) and then windows.onload block to load Jquery events once all the contents on the webpage is loaded